# Every morning, a long running SQL query crashes our WordPress / WooCommerce site

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm about to get crazy over this. Not sure when exactly it started, but since about 4 weeks, every single morning, a long running SQL query crashes our site. I've even installed a monitor to see that: https://monitor.heukelbach.org/

The website goes down at around 6am every day for about 40 minutes, then recovers, goes down again for about 10 minutes and then it's fine for the rest of the day.

It's so heavy that I even cannot login into anything, including PHPMyAdmin. WordPress says "Error establishing database connection".

Now comes the interesting part: I got the chance to catch the query a few times. It always looks like this, and it's clearly something about WooCommerce:

[image: Query, runs for 30-40 minutes]

```
SELECT O8WHc_2_posts.* FROM O8WHc_2_posts LEFT JOIN O8WHc_2_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( O8WHc_2_posts.post_parent = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' ) OR ( O8WHc_2_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' ) LEFT JOIN O8WHc_2_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( O8WHc_2_posts.post_parent = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' ) OR ( O8WHc_2_posts.ID = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' ) LEFT JOIN O8WHc_2_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( O8WHc_2_posts.ID = mt3.post_id AND mt3.meta_key = '_date_paid' ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( NOT mt3.post_id IS NULL AND ( mt3.meta_key = '_date_paid' AND mt3.meta_value >= '1628121600' AND mt3.meta_value <= '1628121600' ) OR O8WHc_2_posts.post_parent > 0 AND ( O8WHc_2_posts.post_date >= '2021-08-05' AND O8WHc_2_posts.post_date <= '2021-08-05' ) ) AND ( ( mt1.post_id IS NULL AND ( mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' AND mt2.meta_value IN ('AT','BE','BG','CY','CZ','DK','EE','ES','FI','FR','GR','HR','HU','IE','IT','LT','LU','LV','MT','NL','PL','PT','RO','SE','SI','SK','MC','GB') ) ) OR ( mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND mt1.meta_value IN ('AT','BE','BG','CY','CZ','DK','EE','ES','FI','FR','GR','HR','HU','IE','IT','LT','LU','LV','MT','NL','PL','PT','RO','SE','SI','SK','MC','GB') ) ) AND (O8WHc_2_posts.post_type IN ('shop_order')) AND (O8WHc_2_posts.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-on-hold','wc-completed')) GROUP BY O8WHc_2_posts.ID ORDER BY O8WHc_2_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 2
```

or

```
SELECT O8WHc_2_posts.* FROM O8WHc_2_posts LEFT JOIN O8WHc_2_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( O8WHc_2_posts.post_parent = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' ) OR ( O8WHc_2_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' ) LEFT JOIN O8WHc_2_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( O8WHc_2_posts.post_parent = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' ) OR ( O8WHc_2_posts.ID = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' ) LEFT JOIN O8WHc_2_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( O8WHc_2_posts.ID = mt3.post_id AND mt3.meta_key = '_date_paid' ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( NOT mt3.post_id IS NULL AND ( mt3.meta_key = '_date_paid' AND mt3.meta_value >= '1628208000' AND mt3.meta_value <= '1628208000' ) OR O8WHc_2_posts.post_parent > 0 AND ( O8WHc_2_posts.post_date >= '2021-08-06' AND O8WHc_2_posts.post_date <= '2021-08-06' ) ) AND ( ( mt1.post_id IS NULL AND ( mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' AND mt2.meta_value IN ('AT','BE','BG','CY','CZ','DK','EE','ES','FI','FR','GR','HR','HU','IE','IT','LT','LU','LV','MT','NL','PL','PT','RO','SE','SI','SK','MC','GB') ) ) OR ( mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND mt1.meta_value IN ('AT','BE','BG','CY','CZ','DK','EE','ES','FI','FR','GR','HR','HU','IE','IT','LT','LU','LV','MT','NL','PL','PT','RO','SE','SI','SK','MC','GB') ) ) AND (O8WHc_2_posts.post_type IN ('shop_order')) AND (O8WHc_2_posts.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-on-hold','wc-completed')) GROUP BY O8WHc_2_posts.ID ORDER BY O8WHc_2_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

I already tried to

- install Query Monitor (Plugin)
- enable SAVEQUERIES (define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );)
- talk to my hosting company (they cannot see the origin of the query either)
- switch of all unneeded plugins

That's my system report from WC:

```
`
### WordPress Environment ###

WC Version: 5.5.2
REST API Version: ✔ 5.5.2
WC Blocks Version: ✔ 5.3.3
Action Scheduler Version: ✔ 3.2.1
WC Admin Version: ✔ 2.4.4
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 5.8
WP Multisite: ✔
WP Memory Limit: 512 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: ✔
Language: de_DE_formal
External object cache: –

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 7.4.19
PHP Post Max Size: 200 MB
PHP Time Limit: 300
PHP Max Input Vars: 10000
cURL Version: 7.58.0
OpenSSL/1.1.1

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.7.34-nmm1-log
Max Upload Size: 127 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

WC Database Version: 5.5.2
WC Database Prefix: O8WHc_2_
Datenbank-Total Size: 1397.50MB
Datenbank-Size: 907.08MB
Datenbank-Index size: 490.42MB
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_sessions: Daten: 5.57MB + Index: 0.21MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_api_keys: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: Daten: 0.89MB + Index: 0.89MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_order_items: Daten: 14.38MB + Index: 6.44MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Daten: 138.62MB + Index: 102.13MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_tax_rates: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_shipping_zones: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_payment_tokens: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_log: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_actionscheduler_actions: Daten: 3.94MB + Index: 1.94MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_actionscheduler_claims: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_actionscheduler_groups: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_actionscheduler_logs: Daten: 3.64MB + Index: 2.26MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_addonlibrary_addons: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_addonlibrary_categories: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_admin_columns: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_aepc_custom_audiences: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_aepc_logs: Daten: 34.40MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_blc_filters: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_blc_instances: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_blc_links: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_blc_synch: Daten: 1.42MB + Index: 0.92MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_borlabs_cookie_consent_log: Daten: 108.04MB + Index: 22.23MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_borlabs_cookie_content_blocker: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_borlabs_cookie_cookies: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_borlabs_cookie_groups: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_borlabs_cookie_script_blocker: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_commentmeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_comments: Daten: 9.63MB + Index: 3.42MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_dlm_order: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_dlm_session: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_download_log: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_duplicator_pro_entities: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_duplicator_pro_packages: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_dynamic_widgets: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_e_submissions: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_e_submissions_actions_log: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_e_submissions_values: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_failed_jobs: Daten: 1.26MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_fg_redirect: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_fpd_categories: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_fpd_category_products_rel: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_fpd_products: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_fpd_views: Daten: 0.14MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_addon_feed: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_draft_submissions: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_entry: Daten: 0.50MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_entry_meta: Daten: 1.25MB + Index: 0.89MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_entry_notes: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_form: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_form_meta: Daten: 0.09MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_form_revisions: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_form_view: Daten: 0.19MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_gf_rest_api_keys: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_hfcm_scripts: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_iwp_backup_status: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_iwp_file_list: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_layerslider: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_links: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailchimp_carts: Daten: 4.38MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailchimp_jobs: Daten: 2.03MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_actions: Daten: 5.15MB + Index: 11.11MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_forms: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_forms_lists: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_form_fields: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_links: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_lists: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_lists_subscribers: Daten: 1.09MB + Index: 2.69MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_queue: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_subscribers: Daten: 1.62MB + Index: 1.93MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_subscriber_fields: Daten: 1.06MB + Index: 1.08MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mailster_subscriber_meta: Daten: 10.49MB + Index: 11.27MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mec_dates: Daten: 0.63MB + Index: 1.13MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mec_events: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_actions: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_forms: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_forms_lists: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_form_fields: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_links: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_lists: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_lists_subscribers: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_queue: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_subscribers: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_subscriber_fields: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_bak_subscriber_meta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_mymail_temp_import: Daten: 2.03MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nextend2_image_storage: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nextend2_section_storage: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nextend2_smartslider3_generators: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nextend2_smartslider3_sliders: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nextend2_smartslider3_sliders_xref: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nextend2_smartslider3_slides: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nf_objectmeta: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nf_objects: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_nf_relationships: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_ninja_forms_fav_fields: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_ninja_forms_fields: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_options: Daten: 4.08MB + Index: 1.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_pmxi_files: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_pmxi_history: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_pmxi_imports: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_pmxi_posts: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_pmxi_templates: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_postmeta: Daten: 103.58MB + Index: 87.30MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_posts: Daten: 12.43MB + Index: 9.97MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_clicks: Daten: 0.03MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_clicks_rotations: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_keywords: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_links: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_link_metas: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_link_rotations: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_post_keywords: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_post_urls: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_reports: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_prli_report_links: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_queue: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_redirection_404: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_redirection_groups: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_redirection_items: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_redirection_logs: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_relevanssi: Daten: 1.47MB + Index: 2.15MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_relevanssi_log: Daten: 5.81MB + Index: 2.48MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_relevanssi_stopwords: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_form: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_form_meta: Daten: 0.07MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_form_view: Daten: 0.11MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_incomplete_submissions: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_lead: Daten: 0.29MB + Index: 0.04MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_lead_detail: Daten: 0.68MB + Index: 0.60MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_lead_detail_long: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_lead_meta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_lead_notes: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_rg_zapier: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_social_users: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_taxonomymeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_termmeta: Daten: 0.12MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_terms: Daten: 0.05MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_term_relationships: Daten: 0.08MB + Index: 0.15MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_term_taxonomy: Daten: 0.06MB + Index: 0.08MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_admin_notes: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_admin_note_actions: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_category_lookup: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_customer_lookup: Daten: 6.74MB + Index: 4.20MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_download_log: Daten: 0.21MB + Index: 0.18MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_order_coupon_lookup: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_order_product_lookup: Daten: 54.03MB + Index: 39.15MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_order_stats: Daten: 5.06MB + Index: 4.19MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_order_tax_lookup: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_product_meta_lookup: Daten: 0.03MB + Index: 0.04MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_reserved_stock: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_tax_rate_classes: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wc_webhooks: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_bundled_itemmeta: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_bundled_items: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_dhl_im_products: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_dhl_im_product_services: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_dhl_labelmeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_dhl_labels: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_packaging: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_packagingmeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipmentmeta: Daten: 20.18MB + Index: 7.30MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipments: Daten: 5.13MB + Index: 2.30MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipment_itemmeta: Daten: 30.32MB + Index: 26.15MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipment_items: Daten: 15.31MB + Index: 15.82MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipment_labelmeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipment_labels: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipping_provider: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_woocommerce_gzd_shipping_providermeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wptc_activity_log: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_wptc_auto_backup_record: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_wptc_backups: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_wptc_backup_names: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_wptc_current_process: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_wptc_excluded_files: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_wptc_options: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wptc_processed_dbtables: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_wptc_processed_files: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_wptc_processed_restored_files: Daten: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
O8WHc_2_yith_wcwl: Daten: 0.97MB + Index: 0.46MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_yith_wcwl_lists: Daten: 1.19MB + Index: 1.99MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_yoast_indexable: Daten: 16.65MB + Index: 5.24MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_yoast_indexable_hierarchy: Daten: 0.19MB + Index: 0.42MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_yoast_migrations: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_yoast_primary_term: Daten: 0.01MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_yoast_seo_links: Daten: 103.08MB + Index: 16.87MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_2_yoast_seo_meta: Daten: 1.53MB + Index: 1.29MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_blogmeta: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_blogs: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_registration_log: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_signups: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_site: Daten: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_sitemeta: Daten: 1.20MB + Index: 0.10MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_usermeta: Daten: 154.49MB + Index: 81.84MB + Engine MyISAM
O8WHc_users: Daten: 9.09MB + Index: 7.53MB + Engine MyISAM

### Post Type Counts ###

acf: 2
acf-field: 3
acf-field-group: 2
attachment: 1289
blocks: 34
da_image: 1
elementor_font: 1
elementor_library: 10
iwp_log: 193
jp_img_sitemap: 1
jp_sitemap: 1
jp_sitemap_master: 1
mec_calendars: 15
mec-events: 5
nav_menu_item: 129
newsletter: 33
nf_sub: 1
oembed_cache: 2
page: 44
post: 9
pretty-link: 2
product: 444
product_variation: 111
shop_order: 42504
sidebar: 1
user_request: 4
wphtmlmail_mail: 16

### Security ###

Secure connection (HTTPS): ✔
Hide errors from visitors: ✔

### Active Plugins (68) ###

Gravity Forms: von Gravity Forms – 2.5.8
Advanced Custom Fields PRO: von Elliot Condon – 5.9.5
Admin Columns: von AdminColumns.com – 4.3.2
Custom Content Shortcode: von Eliot Akira – 3.8.7
Delete Me: von Clinton Caldwell – 3.0
Elementor Pro: von Elementor.com – 3.3.5
Elementor: von Elementor.com – 3.3.1
Extra User Details: von Vadym K. – 0.5
Facebook for WooCommerce: von Facebook – 2.6.1
Fancy Product Designer REST API: von fancyproductdesigner.com – 1.6.4
Fancy Product Designer: von fancyproductdesigner.com – 4.4.1
Geo Redirect: von Ladrower – 3.3.1
Advanced Custom Fields: Gravity Forms Field: von @adam_pope of @stormuk – 1.1.0
Gravity Forms CSS Ready Class Selector: von Brad Vincent – 1.1
Header Footer Code Manager: von 99robots – 1.1.11
Sharing buttons shortcode for Jetpack: von Jeremy Herve – 1.2.2
Language Fallback: von Bernhard Kau – 1.0.5
Loco Translate: von Tim Whitlock – 2.5.3
Login Logout Menu: von WPBrigade – 1.3.1
LoginPress Pro: von WPBrigade – 2.5.0
LoginPress - Anpassen des WordPress Login: von WPBrigade – 1.5.5
Mailchimp for WooCommerce: von Mailchimp – 2.5.2
Manage Notification E-mails: von Virgial Berveling – 1.8.0
Pixel Caffeine: von AdEspresso – 2.3.3
Premium Addons for Elementor: von Leap13 – 4.4.7
Premium Addons PRO: von Leap13 – 2.4.8
Pretty Links Super Affiliate Edition: von Pretty Links – 3.2.3
Regenerate Thumbnails: von Alex Mills (Viper007Bond) – 3.1.5
Relevanssi: von Mikko Saari – 4.13.3.1
Simple Banner: von Ryan Petersen – 2.10.4
Simple Image Sizes: von Rahe – 3.2.1
Simple Page Ordering: von Jake Goldman
10up – 2.3.4

Taxonomy Metadata: von mitcho (Michael Yoshitaka Erlewine)
sirzooro – 0.5

Use Any Font: von Dnesscarkey – 6.1.4
Password Strength Settings for WooCommerce: von Daniel Santoro – 3.0.0
SKU search to direct product page: von Xaraar
firdousi – 1.5

WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor: von WooCommerce – 1.5.13
Germanized für WooCommerce: von vendidero – 3.5.4
WooCommerce Min/Max Quantities: von WooCommerce – 2.4.3
WooCommerce One Page Checkout: von Prospress Inc. – 1.5.5
WooCommerce Product Add-ons: von WooCommerce – 3.0.27
WooCommerce Product Bundles: von SomewhereWarm – 5.7.11
WooCommerce: von Automattic – 5.5.2
Yoast SEO: von Team Yoast – 16.9
WP HTML Mail - Email Template Designer: von Hannes Etzelstorfer // codemiq – 3.0.9
Nested Pages: von Kyle Phillips – 3.1.16
Custom Product Tabs for WooCommerce: von YIKES
Inc. – 1.7.7

YITH WooCommerce Wishlist: von YITH – 3.0.25
WP HTML Mail - WooCommerce: von Hannes Etzelstorfer // codemiq – 2.9.8
User Switching: von John Blackbourn und Mitwirkende – 1.5.7
Limit Login Attempts: von Johan Eenfeldt – 1.7.1
Publish Confirm: von pluginkollektiv – 1.0.2
WP Last Login: von Konstantin Obenland – 4
Login Logo: von Mark Jaquith – 0.10.0
Easy Theme and Plugin Upgrades: von Chris Jean – 2.0.2
Network Username Restrictions Override: von Daniel Westermann-Clark – 1.2
WDS Active Plugin Data: von WebDevStudios – 1.0.1
WP Missed Schedule: von sLaNGjI's Team – 2014.1231.2016.0
WP Change Default From Email: von Subodh Ghulaxe – 1.1.4
Classic Editor: von WordPress-Mitwirkende – 1.6.2
Analytics Germanized for Google Analytics: von Pascal Bajorat – 1.6.1
Borlabs Cookie - Cookie Opt-in: von Benjamin A. Bornschein
Borlabs – 2.2.30

Wordfence Security: von Wordfence – 7.5.4
Better Search Replace: von Delicious Brains – 1.3.4
Allow ePUB and MOBI formats upload: von eKnizky.sk – 1.0
Smush: von WPMU DEV – 3.8.8
Advanced Database Cleaner: von Younes JFR. – 3.0.3



### Dropin Plugins (2) ###

advanced-cache.php: advanced-cache.php
sunrise.php: sunrise.php


### Settings ###

API Enabled: ✔
Force SSL: –
Currency: EUR (€)
Currency Position: right
Thousand Separator: .
Decimal Separator: ,
Number of Decimals: 2
Taxonomies: Product Types: bundle (bundle)
external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)

Connected to WooCommerce.com: ✔



### Product Bundles ###

Database Version: 5.7.11
Template Overrides: –

### Action Scheduler ###

Abgebrochen: 57
Oldest: 2021-07-14 12:49:58 +0200
Newest: 2021-08-13 14:54:52 +0200

Abgeschlossen: 13.797
Oldest: 2021-08-06 09:11:39 +0200
Newest: 2021-08-14 08:00:48 +0200

Fehlgeschlagen: 454
Oldest: 2019-11-09 17:52:58 +0100
Newest: 2021-07-18 05:01:43 +0200

Ausstehend: 6
Oldest: 2021-08-14 12:38:15 +0200
Newest: 2021-08-18 11:35:25 +0200


### Status report information ###

Generated at: 2021-08-14 08:29:40 +02:00
`
```

I am about to download the wp-content folder now to search for everything in it that holds something like "mt1" or "mt2" in it, not sure if that makes any sense at all.

Any ideas what else I could try??

Thanks!

Comment: Did you deactivate the plugins for full day? The query looks like some sort of order processing - are you using Cron to do some order baching etc. or are you using REST API to send orders somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the origin now in a plugin called Germanized:

/woocommerce-germanized/packages/one-stop-shop-woocommerce/src/Queue.php

Line 141:

`public static function build_query( $args ) {
global $wpdb;

```
    $joins = array(
        "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS mt1 ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' ) OR ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_shipping_country' )",
        "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS mt2 ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' ) OR ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key = '_billing_country' )"
    );`
```

I'll contact the developers there now!